# @UniqueConstraint with multiple columns not enforced when using bidirectional mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have these 3 entities :

```
@Entity
class Resource {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "resource", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Element> elements;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "resource_id", nullable = false)
    List<Action> actions;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "element", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_ELEMENT_VALUE_FOR_RESOURCE", columnNames = { "value", "resource_id" }))
class Element {

    String value;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE })
    Resource resource;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "action", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_ACTION_VALUE_FOR_RESOURCE", columnNames = { "value", "resource_id" }))
class Action {

    String value;
    // no reference to Resource
}
```

I have written these two tests :

When I persist a Resource with 2 Actions with the same value, I'm greeted with a `PersistenceException` with an hibernate `ConstraintViolationException` as a cause which is expected:

```
assertEquals(ConstraintViolationException.class, 
    assertThrows(PersistenceException.class, () -> {
        Resource res = newResource("res");
        res.setActions(Arrays.asList(new Action("value"), new Action("value")));
        dao.create(res);
    }).getCause().getClass());
```

When I persist a Resource with 2 Elements with the same value, the creation succeeds and no Exception is thrown.

```
assertEquals(ConstraintViolationException.class, 
    assertThrows(PersistenceException.class, () -> {
        Resource res = newResource("res");
        res.setElements(Arrays.asList(new Element("value"), new Element("value")));
        dao.create(res);
    }).getCause().getClass());
```

If I replace the bidirectional relation with a unidirectional one, my test works.
I don't need the bidirectional relation for Action but I need it in Element.

What am I doing wrong there ? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Is the foreign key created in Element resource_id or is it generated as something else? You haven't specified it in your mappings, so it would be up to the JPA defaults which we cannot determine from what you've left out. Check your logs and the database for what is actually generated and there. Constraints are checked at the database not in JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by calling myself the bidirectional setter in Resource class :

```
@PrePersist
void setBidirectionalMappingsOnPersist() {
    if (elements != null) {
        elements.forEach(element -> element.setResource(this));
    }
}
```

I was thinking that adding the `mappedBy` attribute in the `@OneToMany`, the persistence provider would handle the bidirectional mapping.